# PHP run scripts at dynamic times? Job for cron or no?

Tags: php, cron

I need to run scripts at dynamic times (coinciding with a datetime in a database).  Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Example:

Database says tomorrow at noon in 1 in a datetime field, then i want to run the script tomorrow at noon.

Comment: Do you need down to the minute, or down to the second resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach is to have a cron-job call a PHP script every 1 minute, and have it check the database for things that need done.  If something needs done NOW(), then do it and remove from database.

You need to consider things like locking, process stacking, multiple processes, etc... to make this robust.  But if your need is simple, this is a simple way to make it work.

Add this to crontab:

```
* * * * *   /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/script.php
```

And in /path/to/my/script.php

```
<?php
$ts = time();

// Run for up to 50 seconds
while($ts + 50 > time())
{
   ... SELECT id, job_stuff FROM JobTable WHERE JobDate <= NOW() ...

   process job

   ... DELETE job_stuff FROM JobTable WHERE id = ...

   sleep(5);       
}
```

*Note, this is not robust.  A robust script would grab a record while locked, update it to a "processing" status, process it, and update it to a "complete" status.  This means that multiple processes could work at this same time (even if accidental) and not duplicate jobs.  Also, this means that a single failure would not stop the train.*

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this solution.  I'm looking for something out there that can scale better.  Is there any way to dynamically generate a cronjob?  I could see running a script that goes through the db and creates a cron to run once for each ending time in the db.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "scale" better...  If you want a better solution, write your own daemon that always runs.  You could do automatic scheduling with `atd`, but I wouldn't want to be the one to manage changes to this.  Typically better for your DB to be the master source of the schedule the whole way through.

Comment: PHP can't execute anything unless it's running, so unless you plan on having your script run indefinitely (which is not feasible) you'll need to have a crontab periodically run a script to check whether there's something to execute.

Comment: What do you mean 'grab a record while locked' ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way might have a script that checks the database at reguiar intervals and once it sees a new job create the cron job for that script. You'd obviously need some way to ensure that your processes are updated once they are inserted into the relevant crontab.